# Jenkins Pipeline in OpenShift can not fetch requested repository

Tags: jenkins, openshift, jenkins-pipeline

Just a disclaimer, I'm fairly new on Openshift and Jenkins Pipeline stuff. This is sort of a hello world in jenkins pipeline inside OpenShift, but I cant get it to work. Anyway, here goes. Im going to detail everything that Ive done so far.

I created a new project and application in Openshift using the following set of 'oc' commands:

I created a new project.

```
oc new-project test-project-1
```

I have to create a ssh secret so Openshift can access our gitlab repo.

```
oc create secret generic gitlab-ssh \
    --from-file=ssh-privatekey=./gitlab_openshift_rsa \
    --type=kubernetes.io/ssh-auth
```

I then linked the builder account to the secret.

```
oc secrets link builder gitlab-ssh
```

In order for the secret to be associated to my application, i annotated the secret

```
oc annotate secret gitlab-ssh 'build.openshift.io/source-secret-match-uri-1=ssh://gitlab.hostname.blah/projects/*'
```

I then create the app by issuing the command below:

```
oc new-app codecentric/springboot-maven3-centos~ssh://git@gitlab.hostname.blah/projects/spring-boot-helloworld.git#branch/hello-world --name=springboot-demo
```

In order to test my service, I have to expose it.

```
oc expose svc/springboot-demo
```

I tested this service and everything was working. This means that my ssh key works and Openshift can checkout the repository from Gitlab.

Now I need to be able to create a Jenkins Declarative pipeline to build the same project.

To create a Jenkins Pipeline, I created a hello-world-pipeline.yaml file.

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "BuildConfig"
metadata:
  name: "hello-world-pipeline"
spec:
  source:
    git:
      ref: "branch/hello-world"
      uri: "ssh://git@gitlab.hostname.blah/projects/spring-boot-helloworld.git"
    sourceSecret:
      name: "gitlab-ssh"
  strategy:
    jenkinsPipelineStrategy:
      jenkinsfilePath: Jenkinsfile
```

I ran the command below to create the BuildConfig object in OpenShift.

```
oc create -f hello-world-pipeline.yaml
```

I then go to the Openshift Web Console, Build-Pipelines and Start the Pipeline.

Here is my Jenkinsfile. I apologized if its a bit crude. I know that the build will run twice the first time it executes. oc new-app will call build then Stage 'build' will also do a build.

```
def buildObj;
pipeline {
   agent any
   stages {
      stage('Check Build'){
         when{
            expression{
               openshift.withCluster() {
                  return !openshift.selector('bc', 'springboot-jenkins').exists()
               }
            }
         }
         steps{
            script{
               openshift.withCluster(){
                  echo "Hello from the project running Jenkins: ${openshift.project()}"
                  buildObj = openshift.newApp("codecentric/springboot-maven3-centos~ssh://git@gitlab.hostname.blah/projects/spring-boot-helloworld.git#branch/hello-world","--name=springboot-jenkins")
               }
            }
         }
      }
      stage('Build'){
         steps{
            script{
               openshift.withCluster() {
                  openshift.withProject(){
                    openshift.withCredentials() {
                        echo "Hello from the project running Jenkins: ${openshift.project()} in ${openshift.cluster()}. Lets start the build."
                        buildObj = openshift.selector('bc', 'springboot-jenkins')
                        buildObj.startBuild()
                        /*buildObj.logs('-f') */
                     }
                  }
               }
            }

         }

      }
   }

}
```

This is the error that I'm currently stucked with:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getProject() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:19)
    at com.openshift.jenkins.plugins.OpenShiftDSL.project(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/openshift-client/WEB-INF/lib/openshift-client.jar!/com/openshift/jenkins/plugins/OpenShiftDSL.groovy:269)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:44)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.delegateAndExecute(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.runPostConditions(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:588)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:262)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.catchRequiredContextForNode(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:260)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.runPostConditions(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:587)
```

If I go to the Builds section and look at the springboot-jenkins build log, I can see the following message...

```
Cloning "https://gitlab.hostname.blah/projects/spring-boot-helloworld.git " ...
error: failed to fetch requested repository "https://gitlab.hostname.blah/projects/spring-boot-helloworld.git " with provided credentials
```

Does this have something to do with the source secret that I declared inside the hello-world-pipeline.yaml? I thought the secret works because I was able to test it by creating a new build directly in Openshift. A nudge to the right direction to further debug this is greatly appreciated. I just want to do a build in Openshift using the jenkins pipeline (using jenkins ephemeral inside Openshift) to see how things work.  I might just be missing something basic.

oc version

```
oc v3.9.43
kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
features: Basic-Auth
```

Okay. Now, i was able to make this work. Initially in the oc new-app command i was using the https:// uri and not the ssh:// one, that was the reason for the "failed to fetch requested repository" since the secret was for a ssh key. 
Now, the application can be built successfully, but then i can still see the exception above in my jenkins log and it made the jenkins pipeline fail. Is it because the actual build took longer and the jenkins pipeline cant get a hold of this getProject() object?

Comment: Don't use the source secret match annotation. It seems to be a bit flaky with recent versions of OpenShift for ssh against some Git hosting services. Use the ``--source-secret`` option to ``oc new-app`` or ``oc new-build``, or edit the build configuration and add the secret reference directory to it.

Comment: You can see details of latest best known method for using source secret for private git repository on GitLab at https://cookbook.openshift.org/building-and-deploying-from-source/how-can-i-build-from-a-private-repository-on-gitlab.html This is more up to date that blog posts at blog.openshift.com on the topic.